# Анимация в ячейке таблицы при прокрутке

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Необходимо сделать таблицу, при скроллинге которой будет эффект "точки просмотра". Пример можно посмотреть тут - http://mdigital.ee/test/floors/ (Двигайте мышкой вправо-влево).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если на примере - это много этажное здание, пол и потолок. Между должен быть номер этажа (indexPath.row).

Я не силен в анимации, и не знаю как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста!

Вот что я смог сделать:

```
UIView *myView = cell.demoView;
    CALayer *layer = myView.layer;
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = layer.transform;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1000;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform,45.f * M_PI, 1.0, 0.f, 0.0f);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
            layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
    }];
```

Но строки вращаются синхронно. Есть идеи как это исправить?

Спасибо!

Comment: Анимация на Css ?

Comment: Нет, на objective-c.

Comment: кроме номера этажа что то еще надо там иметь? и номер этажа должен быть написан на самом "полу" или между ячейками?

Comment: номер должен быть написан между ячейками, в дальнейшем добавиться контент в ячейку, но не факт что он будет именно в ней, скорее всего это будет вью поверх таблицы.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну самое сложное вы уже сделали - 3D трансформацию. Осталось простое - отслеживать скрол и применять трансформацию в зависимости от положения ячейки на экране. Например такой вариант:

- `UITableView` наследован от `UIScrollView`, так что вы можете получать от скролл вью делегата информацию о скролле и изменить трансформацию на основании положения ячейки на экране.

**АПДЕЙТ**

вот что у меня получилось. не очень плавно, но я думаю достаточно, как отправной пункт. работает после того, как пользователь начал скролить.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSArray *cells = [self.table visibleCells];
    [cells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITableViewCell *obj, 
        NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    // вот вычисление позиции ячейки (/4 добавил для плавности)
    float position = obj.frame.origin.y/4 + self.table.contentOffset.y;
    CALayer *layer = obj.layer;

    //убрираю старый трансформ перед применением нового, чтоб они не складывались
    layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = layer.transform;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;

    //тут можно бесконечно эксперементировать например position/2 и так далее
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform =
            CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform,
            position * M_PI / 180, 1.0, 0.f, 0.0f);
    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
}];
```

}

Comment: Я добавил все в метод - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView, а вот как получить положение ячейки на экране, пока не смог. Скажем так, детали от пазла есть, но не собрать в единое целое.

Comment: У `UITableView` есть метод `visibleCells` котороый вам вернет массив всех ячеек на экране. А у них уже спросите `frame`

Comment: Да, это я сделал `- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    for ( FloorCellView* cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        [self animateCell:cell];
    }
}`, а вот в методе `animateCell:`и происходит трансформация, но там, я и не могу доделать пока что, строки вращаются в хаотичном направлении =)

Comment: вам надо, как я уже сказал, узнать `frame` каждой ячейки, и применить трансформацию на основании какой то формулы, которая включает в себя `height`

Comment: Спасибо, пытаюсь придумать формулу, пока не вышло =(

Comment: попробую покрутить, если придумаю формулу напишу.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень Вам благодарен, два дня потратил на это, вот хоть чуть-чуть сдвинулся с места.

Comment: как указать мин. и макс. угол наклона, у меня ячейки крутятся или вокруг оси или туда сюда пока прокручиваю таблицу?

Comment: добавил в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду дальше думать как это улучшить!